# SupportMapFragment major lag slowdown after resuming, coming back from another Fragment onBackPressed

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a SupportMapFragment, after I replace this fragment with another fragment, and then press the back key on android, the map suddenly slows down and is almost not responsive or movable. But when I (staying on the slow Map) drag the system notification bar down, and then drag it away again, the map is working without problems.

Does anyone has an idea why this happens? I cant find a solution to this problem.
What is triggered when I drag down the notification bar down and up again?

Here are some code snippets, of how i manage the fragments:

The ContentFragment is the Main Fragment with GoogleMaps, the OverlayFragment is an overlay half the screen size which is showing on top of the map (When I tap on a marker). With the open OverlayFragment, i tap on a button which shows a AlertDialog confirming the user action and then I send an Event via eventbus to the MainActivity managing the fragments, this event closes the OverlayFragment and loads the new ContentFragment, after going back I have the map slowdowns

```
 void setContentFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addBackStack) {
    String fragmentTag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment, fragmentTag);
    if (addBackStack) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

  void setOverlayFragment(@Nullable Fragment fragment) {
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.disallowAddToBackStack();
    final Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_overlay);

    if (currentFragment == null && fragment != null) {
        // Add a fragment
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_overlay, fragment);
    } else if (currentFragment != null && fragment != null) {
        // Replace the fragment
        //ToDo Animation if the heights between layouts are different
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_overlay, fragment);
    } else if (currentFragment != null && fragment == null) {
        // Remove fragment
        collapse(frameLayoutOverlay, new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                fragmentTransaction.remove(currentFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    } else if (currentFragment == null && fragment == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (currentFragment == null || fragment != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    if (currentFragment == null && fragment != null) {
        expand(frameLayoutOverlay);
    }
}

@Nullable
Fragment getContentFragment() {
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_main);
}

@Nullable
Fragment getOverlayFragment() {
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_overlay);
}



  /**
 * Smoothly expands the height of a given View
 *
 * @param v view as instance of ViewGroup
 */
public static void expand(final View v) {
    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
        v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                        ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration((int) (targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }
}

/**
 * Smoothly colapses the height of a given View
 *
 * @param v view as instance of ViewGroup
 */

public static void collapse(final View v, Animation.AnimationListener animationListener) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int) (initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    a.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

Comment: consider adding sample code, and specify exactly which part is causing problem.

Comment: I updated the question with some code